# how to allow only specific number in edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext, numbers

am trying to put only a specific value in my edit text. 
I have used this this my layout.
         `android:digits="0123468"`
however, i also do not want that number 1 and 3 should work in my edit text.

Sample; enter 32... it gives me a list of items
but enter 3 should not allow me to do something.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Set a TextWatcher on your EditText and check/manipulate the input.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an aproach:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/edtNumber"
android:digits="0123456789"
android:inputType="number" />
```

And if you want to discard '1' and '3' you could get input number like this:

```
Integer.parseInt(edtNumber.getText().toString())
```

and compare it with values you don't want.

---

Also if for some reason you want to use decimals do this:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/edtNumberDecimal"
android:digits="0123456789."
android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      String text = s.toString();
      int length = text.length();

      Pattern pattern
        = Pattern.compile("(?s)\\d|[024-9]{2,}");

      if(length > 0 && !Pattern.matches(pattern, text)) {
           s.delete(length - 1, length);
      }
}
```